# Register custom spring expression in spring mvc to use with @Value annotation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using the spring @Value annotation to load a property into my controller from a file.

In my controller....

```
@Value("#{messagesProperties['confirm.priceOverride.fourWeeksOrMore']}")
public String recallOfFourWeeksOrMoreConfirm = null;
```

In my messagesProperties properties file...

```
confirm.priceOverride.fourWeeksOrMore=You have chosen to recall historical data older than four weeks of age. Do you wish to continue?
```

This works but I would now like to put a placeholder in the property file to replace the word four. For example...

```
confirm.priceOverride.fourWeeksOrMore=You have chosen to recall historical data older than {0} weeks of age. Do you wish to continue?
```

The {0} specified in the properties file will be replaced with a value returned from the database which I can get using the following code...

```
Integer priceOverrideRetentionDays = appParamsManager.getPriceOverrideRetentionDays();
```

I have worked out a way to achieve what I want which is as follows...

```
    Integer priceOverrideRetentionDays = appParamsManager.getPriceOverrideRetentionDays();
    recallOfFourWeeksOrMoreConfirm = MessageFormat.format(recallOfFourWeeksOrMoreConfirm, priceOverrideRetentionDays.toString());
```

But I would like to know if there is some way I can do MessageFormat code in the @Value annotation using spring expression language. I've never written a custom spring expression function before, that would be acceptable but I'm not sure how to register it etc.

thanks for your help.

Can someone please help me with how?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spring Expression Language](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) supports static method calls like this:

```
@Value("#{T(java.text.MessageFormat).format(messagesProperties['confirm.priceOverride.fourWeeksOrMore'], appParamsManager.priceOverrideRetentionDays)}")
public String recallOfFourWeeksOrMoreConfirm;
```

This will set the value of `recallOfFourWeeksOrMoreConfirm` to the value returned from the `appParamsManager.getPriceOverrideRetentionDays()` call.  However, the `@Value` annotation is only going to be evaluated once for each instance of your controller.  By default, your controller will be created as a singleton, so if you want this evaluated each time the controller is used, you would need to change the scope of your controller.  For that reason, I would discourage using this approach, but it will work if needed.

Comment: Thank you. Good answer. Based on your comments I am not going to use this because the value from my db could change while the application is alive (although it's not likely)